# MITM Proxy, getting entire request and response string

Tags: python, proxy, mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy for intercepting traffic. What I want is to be able to get the entire request and response in a string. I know that you have `def response(context, flow)` and that the HTTPFlow object has the request and response objects. What I want is simply something like this in a string

```
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1& HTTP/1.1
Header 1: value
Header 2: value

request body
```

and this

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Header 1: value
Header 2: value

response body
```

Now I've been trying this by joing the different parts and bits of the requests and responses but that is prone to errors. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, does mitm handle Gzip encoded response bodies?

Answer (score 7):

If some one bumps into this; the above answer does not work for mitmproxy 4. Instead one can use this:

```
from mitmproxy.net.http.http1.assemble import assemble_request

def response(flow):
    print(assemble_request(flow.request).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole request/response object as a string using `flow.request.assemble()`. If you want the request/response without transfer-encoding (gzip), you can use the decoded decorator:

```
from libmproxy.protocol.http import decoded

with decoded(flow.request):
    data = flow.request.assemble()
```

Apart from that, you may find https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/examples very useful.

Comment: Is the request ever encoded? I used the decoding for the response but I didn't think I'd need it for the request.

Comment: Transfer-Encoding may apply to both requests and responses. For example, you could have a gzipped file upload. Not sure how prevalent this is, but it certainly would be valid HTTP.

Comment: I get the following error: "from libmproxy.protocol.http import decoded
ImportError: cannot import name decoded"