# Import from libmproxy to Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm running a python 2.7 script (on Kali machine) which using the following import:

```
from libmproxy.protocol.http import decoded
```

When running, I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Cannot import name decoded
```

How to fix this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `libmproxy.protocol.http` module doesn't define the name `decoded` which you're trying to `import`. Use the [documentation](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/) for the version of the library you have installed.

Comment: I didn't invented this module. I found a few scripts which use it. It's been used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626213/mitm-proxy-getting-entire-request-and-response-string and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881998/mitmproxy-tampering-get-and-post-request-response-in-one-script I was searching for a solution more than an hour before I posted this thread...

Comment: @Nick: the api may change between versions, so the examples may not work.